# Encog DotNet 3.3 Multithread Error

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, encog

I am getting what seems to be an Encog (3.x) threading / workload error...

Been using Encog CS 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3 with VS.NET 2015 on two servers, each with dual X5400 series 4 core / 4 thread Xeons (8 core / 8 thread system total) without a problem. One has 32Gb RAM and the other 64Gb (though I am only actually seeing 1 busy thread, but that's another story...).

I recently tried the exact same code, compiled (exe) and on the VS IDE on a dual X7500 series 8 core / 16 thread Xeon server (16 core / 32 thread 64Gb system total) and I get this error (with the Encog CS pre-compiled DLL straight from GitHub):

```
System.OverflowException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. at Encog.Util.Concurrency.DetermineWorkload..ctor(Int32 threads, Int32 workloadSize)
 at Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Propagation.Init()
 at Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Propagation.CalculateGradients()
 at Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Propagation.ProcessPureBatch()
 at Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Propagation.Iteration()
 at EncogConsole.modEncog.ElmanTypeA(Boolean boolErrorVerbose, Boolean boolTestOutput) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NormalizedConsole_v4B\EncogConsole\modEncog.vb:line 126
 at EncogConsole.modEncog.Main() in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NormalizedConsole_v4B\EncogConsole\modEncog.vb:line 35
 at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
 at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
 at Encog.Util.Concurrency.DetermineWorkload..ctor(Int32 threads, Int32 workloadSize)
 at Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Propagation.Init()
 at Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Propagation.CalculateGradients()
 at Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Propagation.ProcessPureBatch()
 at Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Propagation.Iteration()
 at EncogConsole.modEncog.ElmanTypeA(Boolean boolErrorVerbose, Boolean boolTestOutput) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NormalizedConsole_v4B\EncogConsole\modEncog.vb:line 126
 at EncogConsole.modEncog.Main() in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NormalizedConsole_v4B\EncogConsole\modEncog.vb:line 35
 at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
 at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() 0.31s
```

The thing here is that the code is the exact same, with the exact same datasets, etc. Tried different code that's running fine on the first two X5400 servers (albeit on what seems to be a single thread) and still the same problem (on the X7500 server). All machines running W2K8R2 with latest patches, etc.

Code is done with VB, but as said before, works just fine, except on this higher thread count server.

What gives?

Comment: I just disabled half the cores and hyperthreading through the BIOS, effectively rendering an 8 core / 8 thread system and lo and behold, Encog came to life, which clearly and squarely makes this an Encog multithreading problem...

Comment: I am interested about ENCOG my self, I still need to steal some time to try it. Based on my experiences the issue with software developed for multiple cores is very often found in race condition that is invisible or does not reveal itself thanks to timing or slow caching on processors with few cores and smaller caches, but as number of cores grow, the chance for race condition to reveal itself is higher.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, although the slowest of the machines mentioned in the original question is a dual 3GHz x 4 cores (8 physical cores total) @ 12Mb L2 cache each, 1333 Mhz FSB and Encog is running fine. All machines are practically idle most of the time. However, the largest machine just had half its cores disabled, along with HT, and Encog ran fine...

Comment: I'm going to debug this to see exactly what is going on... will post back.

Comment: Ok... turns out Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity is giving me {4294967295} which, as I suppose by looking at the code, is meant to return the number of thread, is simply not correctly implemented (var num = (int) (Math.Log(((int) Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity + 1), 2));). I am going to edit the code to get actual number of threads, and I'll post back with results.

Comment: Seems like var num = (int)Environment.ProcessorCount; is a better alternative...

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using:

var num = (int)Environment.ProcessorCount;

instead of:

var num = (int) (Math.Log(((int) Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity + 1), 2));

to get the processor (thread) count in:

Encog.Util.Concurrency.DetermineWorkload > public DetermineWorkload(int threads, int workloadSize)

as var num = (int) (Math.Log(((int) Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity + 1), 2)); returns 4294967295 for a dual cpu, 32 thread system whereas Environment.ProcessorCount correctly returns 32.